# DOCKER REACT MULTI ENVIRONMENTS(development hot live reload, staging, production)

Tags: reactjs, docker

i have a project with React as frontend, NodeJS as backend and MongoDB as persistence. How could i write a single dockerfile for development with live reload and with nginx for production editying only docker-compose? thxx

Comment: It depends what you're aiming for.  I assume you have different Webpack/whatever configurations for prod (minified, etc.) vs. local dev (source maps, hot reload, etc.)?  If you want a single Docker image for both, you're basically going to need to run Webpack/whatever on container startup.  Which doesn't seem ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should utilize `volumes` feature by mapping the code directory into a code directory inside the container that's supposed to live-reload.

Your question is general so I'll post a general steps too, because I don't know what service to stick to in your question.

In general you have two things to cover:

**1. providing latest content to the container**

In your docker-compose file, in the desired service definition you should add a volumes record that will map your local code to the inside-container code like the following:

imaginary project tree:

```
root
  - one-app
    + some.sh
    + Dockerfile
  - second-app
    + some.rails
    + Dockerfile
  - docker-compose.yml
```

imaginary compose file contents:

```
one-app:
   build: one-app/
   volumes:
      - ./one-app:/usr/src/app
   # further definitions

# another services
```

This will get your code inside the container every time it changes.

Now for the second step

**2. Assure your http server will reload on change**

In development environments, using standard `nodejs` http server your app will reload automatically, no configuration required here.

Just for a contrast - in case of `gunicorn` based http servers, you have to provide a startup argument `--reload`

With above configuration your app will reload on code changes.

**edit from comments**

**For development env**

If nginx is not required on development env, then run your app via `npm run serve` or however your run it locally without nginx, with code mapping just like I presented above - it'll work perfectly fine.

So it'll be like below in your compose file

```
one-app:
   build: one-app/
   volumes:
      - ./one-app:/usr/src/app
   command: npm run serve # or whatever command you start a local server with
   # further definitions

# another services
```

**For production env**

or if nginx is required in development env too: in one container you build your app, and in the second one you serve the built app from `nginx`. The basic compose setup would be like this:

```
app:
  # frontend definitions
  volumes: 
    - app-volume:/usr/src/app
  command: "npm run build && cp dist/* /usr/src/app/"

nginx:
  # nginx definitions
  volumes:
    - app-volume:/usr/share/nginx/html
```

The above approach will share the built code with `nginx` and `nginx` will serve it from the public directory that is mapped into `/dist` inside frontend app.

This is how we do it in our company.

Comment: Yep but how could i use nginx for production and only http-server with reload in a single dockerfile?

Comment: Please provide more details in your question. From what I understand you'd like a live-reload on your production frontend app? If so, then it's not done that way. For production you should have a stable version inside a image with all doors locked especially for any kind of live-reloading. For development env's you can simply map the `/dist` to your nginx and nginx will serve whatever it finds in the public directory. Please tell if this is what you meant and i'll update my answer with a bit more detailed instructions.

Comment: Hi dude, i need live reload only for development env, while i need only to run npm run build and copy in  /usr/share/nginx/html the /dist folder for production, how could i make this?